# OCaml: How do I provide fully-qualified module names to avoid name collisions?

Tags: ocaml

I'm working in a package `Foo` with a module called `Base`, but I'd also like to use the OCaml library `Base`. How can I distinguish between the two in `open` statements?

E.g., is there a module-root specifier like in other languages, so I could type `open __root__.Base` or `open __root__.Foo.Base`? E.g. in C++ I could type `::Base` or `::Foo::Base`, where the leading `::` indicates the name is fully qualified starting at root.

Comment: Don't `open` them? You aren't _required_ to open a module to use it.

Comment: If you're concerned that `open Foo` leaves `open Base` ambiguous, you could always do `module B = Base` before opening `Foo`, then `open B`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need to `open` a module to use it. So just refer to them as `Foo.Base` and `Base` respectively.

If you still want to open a module that shadows some definition, then the common practice is to rename the shadowed module before the the open statement, e.g.,

```
module B = Base
open Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

It may also be worth noting that even after opening a module, you can still refer to it using the "full" name.

```
# module A = struct module C = struct let d = 42 end end ;;
module A : sig module C : sig val d : int end end
# module B = struct module C = struct let d = 27.3 end end ;;
module B : sig module C : sig val d : float end end
# open A
  open B ;;
# open C ;;
# d;;
- : float = 27.3
# A.C.d ;;
- : int = 42
# B.C.d ;;
- : float = 27.3
```